# How to display the inventory quantity of a specific variable on the product page?

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, code-snippets

I am creating a form, and I would like to display the amount of inventory remaining for a variable product in a normal text field created with Jet-Engine within the same product or **product page**.

I have tried adding

- _product_attributes
- _stock
- _stock_status
- instock

but none of them show the value.

How do I tell the **instock** to show the remaining amount of inventory of the **variation_id**.

I don't know if I should create an **add_filter** or an **add_action** and associate it with a custom field to be replaced by the new **instock_variation_id** value.

I have installed **JSM's Show Post Metadata plugin** which shows all the product fields but it does not show the fields that each variable has, I have 7 variables of a **single product**.

Could you help me to find the solution?

- I am using Elementor Pro
- The theme is Hello from Elementor
- JetWooBuilder as a customization layer for WooCommerce

Answer (score 0):

Place the following function in your functions.php

```
//This hook will return stock qty under the variation selection
add_action('woocommerce_after_variations_table','show_variation_stock_qty');
function show_variation_stock_qty() {
    global $product;
    foreach ( $product->get_available_variations() as $key ) {
        $variation = wc_get_product( $key['variation_id'] );
        $stock = $variation->get_availability();
        $stock_string = $stock['availability'] ? $stock['availability'] : __( 'In stock', 'woocommerce' );
        $attr_string = array();
        foreach ( $key['attributes'] as $attr_name => $attr_value ) {
            $attr_string[] = $attr_value;
        }
        echo '<br/>' . implode( ', ', $attr_string ) . ': ' . $stock_string;
    }
}
```

This will return something like:

blue: 6 in stock

red: 9 in stock

green: 4 in stock

Comment: No, that code I know, I want is from the product page, extract from the 7 variations, the one I want, for example T-Shirt Size S Color Blue this variation has an ID #300 and the global product ID is for example #15.

I would like through the code to be able to tell the system in a table that is a form a bulk variation table, the quantity, the price and the remaining stock.

So if I want to show for example in the first paragraph the T-Shirt Size S Blue Color.

In the third paragraph show the T-Shirt Size M Color Blue.

In the 6th paragraph show the T-Shirt Size L Color Green.

Next +

Comment: In order to do that, I need a literal form that is connected to that variable, what I can't do is to extract the inventory from that variable, for example T-Shirt Size S Color Blue there are 395 units available out of 500, T-Shirt Size M Color Blue there are 499 units available.

As I want to show separate variables, the limitation is that... it would force me internally to enter custom fields and fill them by hand, since I can't find the key or the hook or loop of the quantity of that specific variable.

Comment: Pass the ids which you want ? and loop those ids ?

Comment: To be easy to query these product ids you can create custom meta that you check and pull all products with checked meta ? What you can do is bulk update at first with a simple query and update that meta and after that when u need to add or remove variable id just go to the product and update it ?

Comment: I already created the code using a shortcode, the only thing I have to put is the variable ID and and code goes and looks for that variable and brings back the amount of stock left.